# Set features of Chrome extension (pop-up) to tabs that will be opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, tabs, popup

I'm developing a Chrome extension that changes some features of web pages (es. text color, background color, link color) chosing them in a pop-up and applying them with jQuery or Javascript. 
Now it works fine for the activeTab when I open the pop-up and choose the colors, but I would like to apply the same features

1. to all the tabs already open in the browser (not only the activeTab)
2. to all future tabs that I can open during the navigation (for example a new tab that will be opened when I click a link in the current web page)
3. finally keep saving that features even when browser is closed, to set them one time browser will be opened again.

For the point 3 I think I have to use the *Chrome storage API*, but I don't know which type and how to use it. Instead for point 1 and 2 I don't know how to proceed.

I put an extract of the current code I have developed.

Popup.js

```
function changeBackground(){
    var color = document.getElementById('backC').value;  //color taken by a color picker

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { type: 'backcolor', bColor: color});
    });
}
```

ContentScript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch(message.type) {

            case "backcolor":
                backgroundColor = message.bColor;
                $("*").css("background-color", message.bColor);
                break;

            default:
                console.error("Unrecognised message: ", message);
        }
    }
);
```

If you can help me finding some solutions for the three points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you need to inform your content to run. In your background script create a tabs onActivated listener. Make sure your content script is listening for this message and runs the desired code.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener({
   message: 'UPDATE_CONTENT_MESSAGE'
})
```